# iOS Insert Row with 2 Date Fields

Tags: ios, database, azure-mobile-services

How does one insert a row into a table that I've created with two sqlserver smalldatetime fields via the windows azure mobile services library?  I'm currently trying to use:

```
[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]
```

to store the date-time value as an NSTimeInterval or double.  However, this causes the following error:

```
Error Domain=com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorDomain Code=-1302 "Error: Bad request."
```

Comment: Multiply the time interval by 1000 and cast to long.

Comment: The insert method expects an NSDictionary object that contains objects and not primitive data types.  So, I believe this doesn't work.

Comment: Then how are you using the result from `timeIntervalSince1970`?  (Presumably you place it in an NSNumber, right?)

Comment: `long long unixTime = (long long) ([dateToConvert timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000.0);  NSNumber* valueToInsert = [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:unixTime];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime fields should be represented by an NSDate field in the NSDictionary object you are sending to insert or update call.

So you would just do:

```
[table insert:@{ @"id": @"myid", @"deliveryDate": [NSDate date] } completion:... ];
```

If you send an NSNumber instead, then you would see the -1302 error shown above.